# How do I prepend a sequential model to a pretrained model in Keras?

Tags: image, keras, tensorflow2.0, prepend

I want to put a 4-layer dense network in front of a pretrained model like nasnet_mobile.  I have tried this several different ways, but they all give headaches (aka errors).  What is the way to do this in keras+tensorflow2 that works?

Thoughts:

- Is there some "flag" where I have to specify the output of the Dense as integer, or picture?
- Is there some "flag" in the pretrained model where I have to allow it to connect?
- Do I need to manually make a clone of the pretrained, load it with pretrained weights, and then try one of the above; perhaps the pretrained are a different class than the created?  (update) If I'm copying, is there an easy way to make sure I get the structure the same so that when I have set_weights(get_weights(…)) it doesn't error?
- None of the above...

CODE:

```
#LIBRARIES
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Reshape, Conv2D, MaxPool2D , Flatten, Input


my_input_shape = (224,224,3)

#DENSE MODEL
my_inputs = Input(shape=my_input_shape)

hidden_1 = Dense(units=8, activation='relu')(my_inputs)


#make the output layer
hidden_2= Dense(units=np.product(my_input_shape), 
                           activation='sigmoid')(hidden_1)

transformed = keras.layers.Reshape(my_input_shape,)(hidden_2)  

dense_model = Model(inputs=my_inputs, outputs=transformed)

#PRETRAINED MODEL
pretrained_model = keras.applications.nasnet.NASNetMobile(weights = 'imagenet', 
                                                            include_top = False,
                                                            input_shape=my_input_shape)

#Option 1
combined_model_1 = keras.applications.nasnet.NASNetMobile(weights = 'imagenet', 
                                                            include_top = False,
                                                            input_tensor=transformed)

#Option 2
combined_model_2 = Model(inputs=dense_model.input, outputs=pretrained_model.output)

#Option 3a
combined_model_3a = keras.applications.nasnet.NASNetMobile(weights = 'imagenet', 
                                                            include_top = False,
                                                            input_tensor=my_input_shape)(dense_model)
#Option 3b
combined_model_3b = keras.applications.nasnet.NASNetMobile(weights = 'imagenet', 
                                                            include_top = False)(dense_model)

#Option 4
combined_model_4 = keras.applications.nasnet.NASNetMobile(weights = 'imagenet', 
                                                            include_top = False,
                                                            input_tensor=dense_model)
```

**Problem:**
Given the above code, I want to daisy-chain the Dense model in front of the pretrained model.  I want to feed an image into dense, have it propagate through dense, then be the input to the pretrained, and go through the pretrained.

Comment: If you put a full code example, we might me able to help. So far I don't see where you are doing wrong, but to me its clear you are doing it wrong.

Comment: If I have relevant but potentially "bad smelling" demo code, would that be okay?

Comment: Yeah of course, any code that reproduces the problem

Comment: Updated.  Is that sufficient? I had 5 or so different ways that this didn't work.  I don't want to make it not work.  I want to make it work.  ;)  If there is any of the failure modes that seemed particularly promising for "resurrection" then let me know and I will try to update appropriately.

Comment: It is updated with all but the exhausting re-creation code from option 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just do this:

```
inp = Input(shape=my_input_shape)
x = dense_model(inp)
x = pretrained_model(x)

final_model = Model(inp, x)
```

Comment: I gave it a shot and it looks like it isn't erroring.  Give me ~10 minutes, and if the larger code doesn't fail then you did it.  Thank you again, for your help and your time.